# USB-C to VGA adapter Apple TV 4

Tags: appletv, vga-adapter

Just out of curiosity: Is it possible to use an [USB-C to VGA adapter](https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MJ1L2ZM/A) with the 4th generation Apple-TV by placing the adapter in the USB-C service port?

Answer (score 2):

No.

From [AppleInsider](http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/09/09/new-apple-tv-uses-usb-c-for-service-ditches-optical-audio-out-port): "Unlike with the 12-inch MacBook, which uses the USB-C port for both charging and syncing, the USB-C connection on the Apple TV will only be used for diagnostics purposes."

Also, from [AppDevice](https://appadvice.com/appnn/2015/10/why-you-may-need-to-get-a-usb-c-cable-for-your-new-apple-tv) "The USB-C cable offers the only way for the new Apple TV to interface with a computer for things like taking screenshots of screen recordings from the device and, more important, restoring the device to factory settings via iTunes (in the event that over-the-air restore doesn’t work)."